# Use online bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

Is it possible to host a bibliography file online and point LaTex to it? The idea would be to host the group citation file online so that instead of everyone have their own local copy they can just use the online one.
This was inspired by matplotlib's stylesheets.

Comment: Yes with `biblatex`. It loads 'bib resources' via `\addbibresource`: e.g., (from the manual) `\addbibresource[location=remote]{http://www.citeulike.org/bibtex/group/9517}` or 
`\addbibresource[location=remote,label=lan]{ftp://192.168.1.57/~user/file.bib}`. See §.3.7.1 on page 76 for details.  (Note: I've never actually tried it.)

Comment: Or (e.g., for `bibtex`) you could use a regular file synchronization solution, like Dropbox, git(hub), rsync, ownCloud, Azure, etc.

Comment: Is there any news here?

Comment: The top comment seems to be correct, I'm not certain how to turn it into an answer for me to accept though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example that seems to work.

```
% LaTeX file: `myfile.tex`
\documentclass{article}
\parindent 0pt % just for this example
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource[location=remote]{https://pastebin.com/raw/cH9cesuJ}
\begin{document}

This is a remote citation \cite{raz1983}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

And then here's a one-entry `.bib` file, which is available on [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/):

```
% BibTeX file as found at https://pastebin.com/cH9cesuJ
% but use the 'raw' version: https://pastebin.com/raw/cH9cesuJ
@Book{raz1983,
  date =         1983,
  author =       {Raz, Joseph},
  title =        {The Authority of Law},
  shorttitle =   {Authority of Law},
  publisher =    {Oxford University Press},
  location =     {Oxford},
}
```

Then the normal sequence of commands:

```sh
latex myfile.tex # note: extensions not strictly needed
biber myfile.bcf
latex myfile.tex
```

Result:

[image: remotebiblatex.png]